# Rigorous definition of space and time order of accuracy of numerical PDEs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, na.numerical-analysis, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Suppose that we are solving numerically a PDE (with a numerical scheme like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1996498)) which involves space $x$ and time $t.$ It is a commonly seen expression in the literature that "the method has order of accuracy $a$ in time, and order $b$ in space".

However the meaning of this statement is never defined clearly in any place I see. For instance, if the local error is $\delta x^4 + \delta x^2 \delta t+\delta t^3,$ is the method 2nd order in time? The $\delta t^3$ term has power 3 but $\delta x^3 \delta t$ only has power 1 in $\delta t$!

I think the question should be very basic for this site. However, it should be appropriate for this size, because it is VERY hard to find a discussion of this on elementary texts, and the advanced research-level texts often do not define it anyway. Apparently, not that many people know about this. Clarifications would be helpful.

[Originally posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4690515)].

Comment: It means the error is $O(\Delta t^a \Delta x^b)$.  In your example, $a=1$ and $b=2$.